# vim-cmd connection refused in management console

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm trying to manage VMs on the local management console of an ESXi 5 host (due to a problem accessing it through VI client and needing to do some VM management prior to attempting a reboot on the host.)

I will enter a command such as:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms
```

and get this error:

```
Failed to login: Connection refused
```

I read somewhere that SSH has to be enabled in order for `vim-cmd` to work.  I'm actually working directly on the host's terminal, not by SSH, but just in case I enabled SSH, and the same error still occurred.

How can I get `vim-cmd` to work in the local management console?

Answer (score 0):

check whether the 'vpxa' service is running, I had the same issue and figured out that the 'vpxa' service was stopped.
after starting the service everything worked well.
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1003490